# ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow - The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign C# SDK (sorry I am new to this) doing a POC at work - created integration key in the demo account.

Using the below example to test authentication.
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/README.md

I keep getting this error - The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled -- even after creating the integration key again.

```
        const string docuSignDemoIntegrationKey = "2ce4-3508-f3b-da8b74d79daf";
        const string docuSignDemoApiUserName = "a1f8--4db8-9a39-2bd4f175";
        string oauthBasePath = "account-d.docusign.com";
        string privateKeyFilename = @"C:\WorkStation\Projects\DocuSign\PrivateKey2.pem";
        int expiresInHours = 1;
        string host = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";

        string accountId = string.Empty;

        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(host);
        apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow(docuSignDemoIntegrationKey, docuSignDemoApiUserName, oauthBasePath, privateKeyFilename, expiresInHours);

        AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(apiClient.Configuration);
        LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
```

Comment: Are you using Admin Consent or User Consent, you can check difference between these two here, https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html  Admin consent needs an Org Admin to configure something in the DocuSign and it is an extra paid feature, where as User Consent needs you to start with Authorization Code Grant or the Implicit Grant then call above JWT method.

Comment: This is a demo account and I need to implement Admin consent

Comment: You need to talk to your DocuSign Account Manager if Org Admin is included in your plan and if it is not included then you need to check price for the same with the DS Account Manager. Once DS Account Manager enables it for you, then only you can use Admin Consent after configuring Integrator Key and Organization in your Demo Account.

Comment: In addition to what Amit has mentioned, it looks like the integrator key is commented out anyways in your code??

Comment: Actually, I had IntegratorKey and UserName assigned to different variables and those are not in above code snipped

Comment: I just changed code snippet - integrator key and user name are not real ones

Comment: @B.VPen: Did you get chance to talk to your DocuSign Account Manager, as Org Admin is not enabled in all DocuSign plan. Admin consent will only work if you configure Organization in DocuSign Web Console after getting Org Admin access. Once configuration is done then you need to call the code to create accesstoken using JWT.

Comment: @B.VPen how did you get the RSA Key file? Is it just a doc file with the keys from dousing account?

Answer (score 0):

As Ergin mentioned in his comment, you need to provide both the client_id (integration key) and the private key in your call.

Comment: In my actual code, I was passing both Integrator key and apiUsername

Comment: I just changed code snippet - integrator key and user name are not real ones

Comment: @B.VPen: I had the same issue as yours and found the solution. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633928/error-when-creating-jwt-token/50299254#50299254)