# Error when creating JWT Token

Tags: c#, docusignapi

As I am on my way to switch from using the [legacy header authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html) method to the [JWT Token](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html#creating-the-jwt-token) method, I have used the following example found [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/README.md).

However, I get the following error :

```
Error calling Login: {
  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}
```

Below is my C# code.

```
string oauthBasePath = "account-d.docusign.com";
string privateKeyFilename = "./private.pem";
int expiresInHours = 1;

ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(docuSignUrl);
apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow(
    "IntegratorKey",
    "USER ID GUID",
    oauthBasePath,
    privateKeyFilename,
    expiresInHours);
AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(apiClient.Configuration);
return authApi.Login();
```

I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400420/configurejwtauthorizationflow-the-specified-integrator-key-was-not-found-or-is?answertab=oldest#tab-top) that shows the similar error but it doesn't seem resolved

Update 05/07/2018: I have validated the domain used in my account but I still get the same error message

Update 05/11/2018: When I use my code but that I replace the IntegratorKey, UserID and private key used in the DocuSign Unit Tests [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/SdkTests/TestConfig.cs), my code now works !? Hence, I can only conclude that the issue doesn't come from my code but maybe a configuration issue on the DocuSign side ? do I need to configure my Integrator Key a specific way ?

Comment: Is you docuSignUrl - https://demo.docusign.net/restapi for Demo? You can check test at [Unit Test](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/SdkTests/JwtAuthUnitTests.cs)

Comment: Yes, this is the Url I use : https://demo.docusign.net/restapi

Comment: Did the [Unit Test] (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/SdkTests/JwtAuthUnitTests.cs) code help? Also can you recheck if Integrator Key changes were saved with the redirectUri or RSA Key Pair.

Comment: No,it didn't help much. I had already used it to create my code (see in my question). I don't understand your second question, I think it's missing words.

Comment: can you please try using jwt.io/ website to generate Assertion, then generate access token using POSTMAN. It will make sure that no issue exists in the configuring IntegratorKey in DS.

Comment: @AmitKBist Is this function `ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow()` supposed to return a token ? I see a property called `AccessToken` but it's set to null upon returning from the function

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Client/ApiClient.cs has the working of `ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow()` method. This method sets `this.RestClient.BaseUrl = baseUrl` and `config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("{0} {1}", tokenInfo.token_type, tokenInfo.access_token));`

Comment: Did this issue get resolve?

Comment: no, it is not resolved yet

Comment: @Frederic How have you added .pem file? I have got my public and private keys but don't know what to do with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation, the reason with such an error is that I was not generating the Authorization Code Grant prior to executing my code.
Based on the information found [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_server.html#scopetable), I had to perform the following HTTPRequest example :

```
GET /oauth/auth?
  response_type=token
  &scope=signature
  &client_id=YOUR_INTERGRATOR_KEY
  &state=a39fh23hnf23
  &redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback
```

Once it is approved, then I can run my code successfully.
In the end, the initial error message is really misleading (I might argue it could be considered a bug ?).

Comment: Will this call leads to login page?

Comment: Yes, it will ask the user to login in order to accept the consent

Comment: can you show me the way of skipping login on client side, so they can just accept and sign the document? I want to authenticate my user with access token but don't want the clients to login. Is there any way?

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala I'm not sure there is a way to skip the consent. As you can see [here](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-using-the-oauth-jwt-flow/), it mentions "Consent is needed!"

Comment: yeah that is I have read but what I'm trying to do is, my app is client app. I don't want my clients to login on my server. I want to redirect them directly to the document to sign. Is it possible?

Comment: Same for me but I haven't found a solution to circumvent that as well... It looks like we're on the same boat!