# Docusign PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled

Tags: docusignapi

I have a web application that I am trying to integrate with Docusign.  I am using the java docusign client.   I started down the path to use OAuth2, but then found out the refresh token expires and from what I am reading the user would have to authenticate again (user interaction each time).  Normally refresh does not expire but access token does.  Am I reading that correctly?

I want the user to authenticate once and for the app to be able to use that token without having to ask the user for access again.  So I started looking at JWT and am not finding the documentation I need.

Using the JWT I can get the user info for the account.  But can't make the call for templates.

```
apiClient.configureJWTAuthorizationFlow(folder + "509.cert", folder 
+ "509.ppk", "account-d.docusign.com", IntegratorKey, account, 3600 );

com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = 
apiClient.getUserInfo(apiClient.getAccessToken());
// **** This prints fine *****
System.out.println("UserInfoxxx: " + userInfo);

// **** Verified the url is demo *****  
apiClient.setBasePath(userInfo.getAccounts().get(0).getBaseUri() + 
"/restapi");
com.docusign.esign.api.TemplatesApi api = new 
com.docusign.esign.api.TemplatesApi(apiClient);

try {
    com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeTemplateResults resp = 
    api.listTemplates(account);
    for ( com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeTemplateResult template : 
resp.getEnvelopeTemplates() )
    {
            out.println("X " + template.getDescription() + " " + 
template.getName() );
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi
com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, 
received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response Body: '{
"errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
"message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled.  
Invalid account specified for user."}'
at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:929)
    at   
com.docusign.esign.api.TemplatesApi.listTemplates(TemplatesApi.java:2471)
    at 
com.docusign.esign.api.TemplatesApi.listTemplates(TemplatesApi.java:2409)
```

I am using my integrator key (client id) 
Any suggestions or advise?

[Update]
Yes I am here is my flow.

Send the user to

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=" + IntegratorKey + "&redirect_uri=" +     redirectUri + "&state=" + state;
```

On redirect

```
String code = request.getParameter("code");
com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.generateAccessToken(IntegratorKey, ClientSecret, code);

System.out.println("OAuthToken: " + oAuthToken.getAccessToken() );

com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(oAuthToken.getAccessToken());

String folder = com.n.util.Settings.getInstance().getRealPath("/") + "META-INF/cert/";
apiClient.configureJWTAuthorizationFlow(folder + "509.cert", folder + "509.ppk", "account-d.docusign.com", IntegratorKey,             userInfo.getSub(), oAuthToken.getExpiresIn() );
```

I then store userInfo.getSub() and use that in the other requests.
I have tried the account id as well.

Comment: Are you making sure to get the consent from the user ? Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633928/error-when-creating-jwt-token/50299254#50299254) for a possible solution

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   Yes I am asking the user to authorize the app.  Is there a way to see the authorized apps in the docusign account?    I updated the original post with the flow see below [Update]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Re: I started down the path to use OAuth2, but then found out the refresh token expires and from what I am reading the user would have to authenticate again (user interaction each time).
>
> Normally refresh does not expire but access token does.
>
> Am I reading that correctly?

**Not completely.** Please use Authorization Code Grant as you originally planned.

Here's the scoop: if you ask for the `extended` scope (in addition to the `signature` scope) then the returned refresh token will be good for **another** 30 days every time your app uses the refresh operation.

Example:

Day 1: Human logs into DocuSign using Authorization Code Grant flow via your app. The scope request is `signature%20extended` Your app receives back from DocuSign an `Access Token` good for 8 hours and a `Refresh Token` is good for 30 days. Your app stores the refresh token in non-volatile storage.

Day 23: Human again wants to use your app with DocuSign. Your app uses the Refresh Token it stored to make a refresh token request to DocuSign. (No human interaction is needed.) Your app receives back an Access Token, good for 8 hours, and a **new** `Refresh Token` good for 30 days from now (until day 53). Your app stores (replaces) the Refresh Token in non-volatile storage.

**Result** As long as your app uses/refreshes the refresh token at least once every 30 days, it will forever have a DocuSign refresh token can be used to obtain an Access Token, with no human interaction needed.

**Caveat** A security issue initiated by the DocuSign customer or by DocuSign itself may cause the Refresh and/or Access token to be no longer valid, and thus require that the user manually authenticate to DocuSign. But this would be an unexpected event and would also affect Access Tokens obtained via the JWT Authentication flow.

**Please reserve the JWT flow for the cases where it is required.** The JWT flow enables your app to **impersonate** the user. This is a higher level of access and thus should not be used if there is a good alternative. If the user is present then Authorization Code Grant is the recommended authentication flow.

**Re your problem with the JWT flow:** Try out our new [Java JWT example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt/) to see if it helps.